# Replacing characters in a string based on mapping two sets of characters in Java

Tags: java

I have edited two strings and can covert them to character maps. I am trying to think through the best way to map and replace based off of these two strings. For example: I have a word that I append to the front of the alphabet based on user input. In this example cat(catdefghijkl..). I then take a sentence and replace characters in it based on my new alphabet. (now a would be c, b would be a, c would be t). I am not looking for code but just input on the best way to accomplish this. Can you map two strings or character maps together and then do a replace based on those mappings?

Comment: Why don't you just try something - then you might end up with a concrete and answerable question that is fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map<Character, Character>`.

The key could be the regular alphabet letter, and the value could be the new letter.

```
Map<Character, Character> newAlphabet = new HashMap<>();
List<Character> regularAlphabet = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c');//put complete alphabet here

public void updateAlphabet(List<Character> newLetters) {
    assert (newLetters.size() == 26);//or 52 for uppercase
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    newAlphabet.clear();
    regularAlphabet.stream()
            .forEach(letter -> newAlphabet.put(letter, newLetters.get(i.getAndIncrement())));
}

public String replaceString(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    s.chars().forEach(c -> sb.append(newAlphabet.get((char) c)));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Please note, this code is not thread safe.  Its just for testing out the idea of using a Map to map the regular alphabet to the decoded alphabet.

> Could I map my two alphabet strings using a hashmap?

If the goal is to replace whole String with replacement Strings then that is also possible.  For that you would use a `Map<String, String>` to store the mappings.  You can then use String's `replaceAll` method to find the initial String and replace it with a new String.

```
//the key represents a String that would need to be replaced with the value String
Map<String, String> stringMapping = new HashMap<>();

public String replaceString(String s) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : stringMapping.entrySet()) {

        s = s.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Could I map my two alphabet strings using a hashmap?